# Is it possible to configure dpdk RSS so that requests sent from a particular tx queue will have their responses returned on a specific rx queue?

Tags: networking, dpdk

I am attempting to use dpdk with multiple `rx` and `tx` queues on a single physical port. The goal is to have each thread send Rpcs (with some identfier inside the packet) on its own `tx` port, and receive the responses on its own `rx` queue.

However, in order to have the responses return to the correct queue, I need to configure `rss` to direct the response packets based on some identifier in the request.

Logically, I'd want to stamp my request packets with the queue id of the tx queue they're being sent over, and the server side of the rpc would stamp the responses with the same queue id; the goal would be for the hardware to read the stamp and direct the response packet to the correct hardware queue.

Based on the [dpdk documentation](http://dpdk.org/doc/api/structrte__eth__rss__conf.html), it seems that I can only specify a hash key rather than an arbitrary function to decide which `rx` queue an incoming messages will arrive in. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find the source code or documentation demonstrating how this hash key is used (which may be because it is in hardware), so I cannot arrange my packets accordingly.

Is there some way to use the hash key to get the effect of matching requests and responses?

Alternatively, is there some way to have dpdk run an arbitrary function to determine the correct destination queue for an incoming packet?

Answer (score 0):

> is there some way to have dpdk run an arbitrary function to determine the correct destination queue for an incoming packet?

If we need to divert some traffic to a specific queue, there is [Generic flow API](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/prog_guide/rte_flow.html) in DPDK.

For a start, please have a look at [Flow API Examples](https://dpdk.org/doc/guides/howto/rte_flow.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to use the hash key to get the effect of matching
> requests and responses?

Yes. You probably want a **symmetric RSS key**, for example:

```
0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a,
0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a,
0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a,
0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a,
0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x5a,
```

Say, your client application sends packets to some fixed L4 **DST** (server's) port. For a given RPC transaction, it can choose a *dynamic* (*private*) L4 **SRC** port (`49152-65535`). Once the packet is constructed, software RSS implementation (`lib/hash/rte_thash.h`) can be used to compute a **4-tuple** hash. The hash can then be used to dispatch the packet to a specific Tx queue, based on the indirection table. Alternatively, your application may pre-assign a handful of **SRC** port numbers to Tx queues "at start of the day" and then use a specific port number when sending packets via a given Tx queue.

The server responds, and what has been **DST** becomes **SRC**, and vice versa. Thanks to the aforementioned **symmetric key**, when the client's NIC has computed the hash, the packet will land on the right Rx queue.

The short of it, one may exercise a **symmetric RSS key** to achieve the described behaviour. It is not necessary to have the NIC include some custom field (RPC ID, for example) to the hash input set as long as it is possible to leverage different **SRC** port numbers bound to specific Tx queues at the client side.